# Android custom listview with Checkbox checked and unchecked?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have a SpinnerView with two seperate Linearlayouts with Textview 1, Active and 2, Finished.
Under the Active Layout i have a listview with textview and checkbox(unchecked).under the Finished layout i have a listview,Once the Listitem with the checkbox is checked it must move to Finished layout.Can anyone explain me how to implement this, Thanks in advance.
here is my xml file!!

```
 <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollVie2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView2"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:visibility="invisible"
                 android:textSize="25dp"
                 android:text="Active" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listv"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="356dp" >
        </ListView>
         <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView2"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:visibility="invisible"
                 android:textSize="25dp"
                 android:text="Finished" />



              <ListView
                  android:id="@+id/listv1"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="218dp" >

        </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: listview inside a scroll view? never put listview inside a scroll view

Comment: yes the listview is under the scrollview!

Comment: for the first list i have inserted the datas using cursoradapter!!

Comment: if i have above 30 list in the page how can i view???i am new to android...also i didnt put the listview directly in the scrollview inside the linear layout i have a listview for linear layout i gave scrollview!!

Comment: use listview but remove scroll view. you can add your testview as header and footer to listview

Comment: can i get any example for how implement my question!!coming to u..in the header i have uncheck listitems...how move the checkeditem to footer view!!